# Get subfolder svn revision in TeamCity

Tags: svn, teamcity, versioning

We have a strange way of using repos here (and I have little control over it I'm afraid), where a root repo holds multiple projects... no fancy stuff like trunk/tags/branches folder either... (I'm so sad).

So for example the structure looks like this:

```
http://my.svn.root/main
                      |-- /Project1
                      |-- /Project2
                      ...
```

and so on...

Now, doing `svn log` on the folders will give me the latest revision number in that folder. Problem is that TeamCity seems to be doing `svn info` on the root, so even if I specify a VCS root like this:

```
http://my.svn.root/main/Project1
```

the `%build.vcs.number%` property seems to be picked from the `main` root of the repo, so a commit in Project2 will actually advance that number (which is not what I would like).

Is there a way to tell TeamCity to use the subfolder latest commit number rather than the root revision? or a different property that does just that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, apparently it's all due to the VCS root settings. Basically the best option would be to have a root set up to the main and then edit the checkout rules:

```
VCS root: http://my.svn.root/main

checkout rules: +:Project1=>.
```

This seems to be a lot more stable and also more responsive in terms of Build triggering.

Comment: This is great advice. It should be included on a TeamCity Best Practices page.

Comment: Still does not work on TeamCity 8 (( . it returns value of the  most recent revision no matter what branch you do checkout.